# JAXB objects - hashcode and equals

Tags: java, jaxb

We have a huge java application that entirely works based on JAXB serialization.The middleware server does all db access and sends all the data Objects in JAXB objects and serializes to  XML and sends the data to  UI ( C#.Net).

Most of the times after the data is populated from db access into the JAXB java objects , I will have to some processing like "sort the collection of objects based on attribute" , find the avg , do some calculation on  the list of objects in the collection etc.

My major problem is, JAXB objects don't have equals and hashcode. So what I am doing is moving all the data to some user defined Data objects where I have hashcode, equals, compareTo defined so I can do all operations in the collections and then copy to the JAXB objects. I think this is a extra overhead.

Questions:

1) does jaxb objects support equals /hashcode/ compareTo - can I specifiy these in schema?

2) Any other better alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

unfortunately, jaxb does not provide this out of the box.  you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins), or write your own for more customizable behavior.

Comment: plugin has changed location: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-JAXB-Plugins

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to do use [Collections.sort(list, Comparable)](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/) to accomplish the sorting that you want.  Equals and hashcode won't help either of the cases you mentioned since your cases rely on comparison of specific attributes, not the object as a whole.

The other cases of finding averages and performing calculations also have nothing to do with equals/hashcode that I can see.  These operations would simply require parsing the lists and performing your appropriate algorithm.

Comment: This is a good idea to replace the compareTo. But My problem is not only sorting. I do all kind of processing like constructing a nested tree of these objects where I need to put them in hashmap etc. I need to have workaround for hashcode and equals as well;

Comment: This is a different scenario than your actual question.  You would also have to further define the requirements for your nested tree that explain the need to override equals/hashcode.  So far you are saying that you need to override, but haven't given any good reason why.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, while the JAXB-generated Java classes will not have equals and hashcode, you can add these  overrides in the classes you write with JAXB annotations - JAXB will ignore the methods.

Comment: I may have been unclear- I meant that classes with annotations can also have equals and hashcode, not that equals and hashcode can be added using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

[maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) can generate hashcode and equals method using its own plugin: [org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-JAXB-Plugins). More details about configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuration-Cheat-Sheet).

The relevant parts of the pom.xml are as follows:

```
<project
  <!-- other configuration -->
  <dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
          </args>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
              <version>0.11.0</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
          <cleanPackageDirectories>true</cleanPackageDirectories>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```