# Checking equals for JAXB object considering some of the fields

Tags: java, collections, guava

My autogenerated JAXB Class

```
public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String department;

   /* Getters and Setters */

}

Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setId(1);
emp1.setName("A");
emp1.setDepartment("D1");


Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setId(2);
emp2.setName("B");
emp2.setDepartment("D1");

List<Employee> empList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
empList1.add(emp1);
empList2.add(emp2);

Employee emp3 = new Employee();
emp2.setId(3);
emp2.setName("A");
emp2.setDepartment("D1");

List<Employee> empList2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
empList2.add(emp3);
```

> I want to compare both the list empList1 and empList2 and get a result list which matches name and department fields of Employee object.

Basically, I need intersection of two list based on the custom comparison of the fields in two objects.

I was looking at Google Guava and lambdaJ but I was not able to find a solution/sample for doing intersection by custom comparison logic.

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For comparing you can use a Guava Ordering or a Java Comparator. And for filtering you can use a predicate.

If you want something general you can use make one comparator(for both DEP and NAME)

```
    class MyComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Employee left, final Employee right) {
            return ComparisonChain.start().compare(left.getName(), right.getName())
                                  .compare(left.getDepartment(), right.getDepartment()).result();
        }

    }

    class MyPredicate implements Predicate<Employee> {

        final List<Employee> employees;
        final Comparator<Employee> comparator;

        public MyPredicate(final List<Employee> employees, final Comparator<Employee> comparator) {
            this.employees = employees;
            this.comparator = comparator;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable final Employee input) {
            for (final Employee e : employees) {
                if (comparator.compare(e, input) == 0) {
                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Then u can use it like this:

```
    final MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator();
    final MyPredicate predicate1 = new MyPredicate(empList1, comparator);
    final MyPredicate predicate2 = new MyPredicate(empList2, comparator);
    System.out.println("####");
    System.out.println(Collections2.filter(empList2, predicate1));
    System.out.println(Collections2.filter(empList1, predicate2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Employee> findIntersections(List<Employee> listA, List<Employee> listB)
{

    List<Employee> returnList = new List<Employee>();
    Employee empA, empB;

    for(int i = 0; i<listA.size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<listB.size; j++)
        {
            empA = listA.get(i);
            empB = listB.get(j);

            if(empA.getID == empB.getID() && empA.getName().equals(empB.getName()) && empA.getDepartment().equals(empB.getDepartment()))
            {
                returnList.add(empA);//or add empB...since theyre the same
            }
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

> I want a generic implementation. There are lot of JAXB objects which
>   require equal check based on fields. Is there something similar to
>   Comparator which has a method to return boolean?

Here's what I found (you may need a plugin):

> unfortunately, jaxb does not provide this out of the box. you can use
>   this [plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins), or write your own for more customizable behavior.

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771776/2498729

Comment: I want a generic implementation. There are lot of JAXB objects which require equal check based on fields. Is there something similar to Comparator which has a method to return boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Manually hacking down a method to intersect the two lists would be the fastest way of doing it. But if you need a more general aproache for something other than `Employee` for example you could use guavas `Equivalence` class. With that you could map the entries in the lists to an `Equivalence.Wrapper` and use `Sets.intersect` on those Sets of Wrappers.

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersect(Iterable<? extends T> a, Iterable<? extends T> b, Equivalence<? super T> eq) {
    Function<T, Wrapper<T>> f = wrappingFunction(eq);

    Set<Wrapper<T>> as = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.transform(a, f));
    Set<Wrapper<T>> bs = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.transform(b, f));

    SetView<Wrapper<T>> intersection = Sets.intersection(as, bs);

    return ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.transform(intersection,
            Test.<T> unwrappingFunction()));
}
```

where `wrappingFunction()` and `unwrappingFunction()` are there two utility functions:

```
    public static <T> Function<T, Wrapper<T>> wrappingFunction(
        final Equivalence<? super T> eq) {
    return new Function<T, Wrapper<T>>() {
        public Wrapper<T> apply(T input) {
            return eq.wrap(input);
        }
    };
}

private static final Function<Wrapper<Object>, Object>  UNWRAPPING_FUNCTION = new Function<Wrapper<Object>, Object>() {

    public Object apply(Wrapper<Object> input) {
        return checkNotNull(input).get();
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Function<Wrapper<T>, T> unwrappingFunction() {
    return ((Function<Wrapper<T>, T>) ((Function<?, ?>) UNWRAPPING_FUNCTION));
}
```

with this in place you would have to implement `Equivalence` for `Employee` and apply `intersect`

```
Set<Employee> x = intersect(a, b, new Equivalence<Employee>() {

        @Override
        protected boolean doEquivalent(Employee a, Employee b) {
            checkNotNull(a);
            checkNotNull(b);
            return Objects.equals(a.getId(), b.getId())
                && Objects.equals(a.getDepartment(), b.getDepartment())
                && Objects.equals(a.getName(), b.getName());
        }

        @Override
        protected int doHash(Employee t) {
            return t.getId();
        }
    });
```

In this example the returned `Set` would not contain duplicate `Employees`.